# What's the etymology of まほし?

Tags: etymology, auxiliaries, old-japanese

What's the etymology of まほし? Considering it goes after the 未然形, is it something like む -> ま (未然形) + [欲]{ほ}し, or is it a totally different etymology altogether?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *-(a)maposi* optative auxiliary adjective is indeed connected with ほし "want," but the first part is different. It is derived from the simplification of *-(a)maku [nö] posi,* where:

- *-(a)m-* is trivially the ordinary modal (Classical む／ん);
- *-aku* is the nominal ending;
- *posi* is ほし "is desirable."

In Nara Old Japanese, the construction is still attested in the non-contracted form:

栲領巾乃懸巻欲寸妹名乎 (MYS 3.285)
taku pire-nö **kakë-m-aku posi**-ki imo=nö na=wo
"I want to say the name of my love as if hang the scarf of mulberry"

Literally, "hanging is desirable." When the nominal form in *-aku* was lost, the construction was grammaticalized.

In Old Japanese, *-(a)maku [nö] posi* is only used with a limited series of verbs (citing Vovin): *kakë-* 'to hang = to mention,' *kagapur-* 'to obtain,' *kik-* 'to hear, to listen,' *mor-* 'to guard, to protect,' *mi-* 'to see, to look,' *sömë-* 'to dye,' *ne-* 'to sleep.' Since Heian, the grammaticalized descendant loses these limitations, and even in Taketori we find:

あるいはをのがゆかまほしきところへいぬ "As for some, they went towards the place they wanted **to go**," with *yuk-* "to go" not in the previous list. Probably this implies it was completely analyzed as a part of the verb's conjugation pattern.

Sources and further reading:

- Frellesvig, Bjarke - A History of the Japanese Language - Cambridge University Press (2010), pp. 240-2
- [Handbook of Oriental Studies. Section 5 Japan 16] Vovin, Alexander - A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese (2 Vols.) - Brill (2020), pp. 694-8.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I actually saw 〜まく欲し many times before (it's even used as in example sentences in a few dictionaries) but never made the connection between it and まほし. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, where does the _no_ come from?  This generally only connects two non-inflecting words, and ほし inflects as an adjective.  I'm not aware of other cases of `[NOUN]`の`[ADJ]` constructions like this.  Do Frellesvig and Vovin insert the _no_ here?  If so, do they explain why, and what function it has?

Comment: It is not hard to find attestations of that: 4.584 見巻之欲寸 mimaku nö posiki, 10.1913 
見巻之欲 mimaku nö posiki, 20.4449 美麻久能富之伎 the most blatant, mimaku nö posiki (funnily, all with the same verb, but it is generally the most frequent to be used in this construction.) Old Japanese adjectives are much more of nouns than on the later stage, and probably this shouldn't be considered something special.

Comment: Very interesting. Digging around further, the [日本国語大辞典 entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AE-596099#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8)'s sense [1].[四].② gives the definition 「好悪の感情や希望・可能の対象を示す」, with a quote from [MYS 11.2554](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man11Yo.html#2554) using the same _mimaku nö posiki_ construction.  Parent sense [1].[四] defines this usage of の more broadly as 「主格を示す助詞」, which would fit this `[NOUN]`の`[ADJ]` grammar here before が developed its "subject" sense. 古語の勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: A later afterthought. The great expansion of the verbs allowed with まほし between Man’yōshū and Taketori could more plausibly be explained by dialectal shift, from the speech of Nara capital to the speech of Heian region. It is likely that the Nara dialect was especially conservative in this aspect, not that suddenly lost of new verbs were allowed.